# Magento 2.1.7 order saving error: SQLSTATE[42S02]:

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, magento2

I have just tried to add a custom order for testing purposes but I get this error:

```
Order saving error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_.sequence_order_1' doesn't exist, query was: INSERT INTO `sequence_order_1` () VALUES ()
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error strong said that table hast not found in database.

so the things that you can do.

1.check the database is table exist or not

2.if table exist then look properly is your table name correct in the script